# Android studio - Send key events on service

Tags: android

I'm trying to send key events in a service, I know this is not something you should do, however I want to know if there is a way to do it.

I have tried to put a floating widget on the screen so it will have focus, but I couldn't manage to do it.

Here is the key even sending code :

```
        String keyCommand = "input keyevent " + 
        KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE;
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        runtime.exec(keyCommand);
```

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_A:
            //A
            return true;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_B:
            //B
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onKeyUp(keyCode,event);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for asking but how will it help? Where should I put it? I think the problem is that you can't send events without focus, so I don't really see how this will help...